# Dockerfile cannot run a container using "docker-compose-up --build" command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile cannot run a container using "docker-compose-up --build" command

When I run Dockerfile using the "docker-compose up --build" command, the file not found is output, and the container is not running.

Dockerfile, docker-compose.yaml, directory and result is below.

Docker version :

```
\server>docker --version
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine3.10

RUN mkdir -p /app/workspace/config && \
    mkdir -p /app/workspace/lib && \
    mkdir -p /app/workspace/bin

WORKDIR /app/workspace
VOLUME /app/workspace

COPY ./bin ./bin
COPY ./config ./config
COPY ./lib ./lib

RUN chmod 774 /app/workspace/bin/*.sh

EXPOSE 6969

WORKDIR /app/workspace/bin

ENTRYPOINT ./startServer.sh
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    container_name: cn-server
    build:
      context: ./server/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "6969:6969"
    volumes:
      - ${SERVER_HOST_DIR}:/app/workspace
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge
```

directories :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmlxk.png)

"docker-compose up --build" command execution result :

```
Building server
[+] Building 3.7s (13/13) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 425B                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:14-jdk-alpine3.10                                                                                                                                                       2.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 239B                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => CACHED [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:14-jdk-alpine3.10@sha256:b8082268ef46d44ec70fd5a64c71d445492941813ba9d68049be6e63a0da542f                                                                                          0.0s 
 => [2/8] RUN mkdir -p /app/workspace/config &&     mkdir -p /app/workspace/lib &&     mkdir -p /app/workspace/bin                                                                                                                 0.4s 
 => [3/8] WORKDIR /app/workspace                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s 
 => [4/8] COPY ./bin ./bin                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 => [5/8] COPY ./config ./config                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s 
 => [6/8] COPY ./lib ./lib                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 => [7/8] RUN chmod 774 /app/workspace/bin/*.sh                                                                                                                                                                                    0.5s 
 => [8/8] WORKDIR /app/workspace/bin                                                                                                                                                                                               0.1s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.2s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.2s 
 => => writing image sha256:984554c9d7d9b3312fbe2dc76b4c7381e93cebca3a808ca16bd9e3777d42f919                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker_cn-server                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
Creating cn-server ... done
Attaching to cn-server
cn-server        | /bin/sh: ./startServer.sh: not found
cn-server exited with code 127
```

Also bin, config, lib directories are not created in host volume directory and no files.

Please tell me what I was wrong or what I used wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You're mounting `$SERVER_HOST_DIR` on top of `/app/workspace`, which hides any content in that directory (so e.g. `/app/workspace/bin/startServer.sh` is no longer available). We don't know enough about what you're trying to do to suggest the correct solution.

Comment: same result is occurred when I remove the all volumes in docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: I see what the volume does. Thanks larsks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two obvious problems here, both related to Docker volumes.

In your Dockerfile, you switch to `WORKDIR /app/workspace` and do some work there, but then in the Compose setup, you bind-mount a host directory over all of `/app/workspace`.  This causes all of the work in the Dockerfile to be lost, and replaces the code in the image with unpredictable content from the host.  In the `docker-compose.yml` file you should delete the `volumes:` block.  You should be able to reduce what you've shown to as little as

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - '6969:6969'
```

The second problem is in the Dockerfile itself.  You declare `VOLUME /app/workspace` fairly early on.  This is unnecessary, though, and its most visible effect is to cause later `RUN` commands in that directory to have no effect.  So in particular your `RUN chmod ...` command isn't happening.  Deleting the `VOLUME` line can help with that.  (You also don't need to `RUN mkdir` directories you're about to `COPY` into the image.)

```bash
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app/workspace
COPY ./bin ./bin
COPY ./config ./config
COPY ./lib ./lib
RUN chmod 0755 bin/*.sh

EXPOSE 6969
WORKDIR /app/workspace/bin
CMD ["./startServer.sh"]
```

There are other potential problems depending on the content of the `startServer.sh` file.  I'd expect this to be a shell script and its first line to be a "shebang" line, `#!/bin/sh`.  If it explicitly names GNU Bash or another shell, that won't be present in an Alpine-based image.  If you're working on a Windows-based system and the file has DOS line endings, that will also cause an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll modify the docker volume and etc. Thank you.